# Related to PopUp frame

Tags: java, swing, popup, tooltip

I have created popup frame,which is visible when mouse pointer is placed on button.
But the popup frame is getting displayed  at top-left corner of the screen.
How can i get popup in the form of tooltip of the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you googled just that "JButton tooltip"? Here's the [first hit with an example:](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/Settooltipforbutton.htm)

about the pop-up frame being in the top-left corner; it's displayed at the default location which is (0,0). You can set it's location by using the [`setLocation()`][2] method

[2]: https://web.archive.org/web/20130715065613/http://docs.oracle.com:80/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setLocation(int, int)

Comment: But setting the location will not be helpful,when resolution of  screen changes.For that reason only,i thought it is better to have popup in the form of tooltip....

Comment: I do not disagree that the tooltip is a better solution to get tooltip information. :) It all depends on what you are trying to achieve of course, but at any case, you can set the location either by numeral constants or by getting a desired point on the screen, for instance the center point of the screen. This way you can be sure where the component is displayed regardless of the screen resolution.